# ASP.Net MVC BP Get data from alternative Datasource not stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm about to create an application to show different status from objects that are stored at different locations.

To simplify I'll show one of the datasets:

Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
    }
    public Employee(User p)
    {
        Firstname = p.Person.Firstname;
        Lastname = p.Person.Surname;
        Department = new Department(p.Person.Department);
    }
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression("\\d{,10}")]
    [Display(Name = "SAP Pno.")]
    public string SapPersonalNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

other that the other properties "User" is not mapped in my database but can be retrieved by calling an API (Connection to AD).
So when an Employee object is created the Property User is always null which leads to my question:

In my EmployeeRepository I've created a Method that takes an Employee object and returns a User object but who should be responsible for adding the User object to the Employee object?

Should this be handled inside a VM / Controller, should the Repository itself set the Employee's User object and return the finalized Employee object instead of the User object or are there other solutions I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: As a side note, if your editing this and submit a form, it will throw an exception because there is no parameterless constructor

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your reply but on top of my model there is a parameterless constructor :)

Comment: Formatting your code helps :) But this will probably be closed as opinion based

Comment: Okay, so this is just a matter of opinion... thought there is a best practice or something... :(

Comment: Personally I would have the controller call a service that gets `Employee` from the database, and call another service that get the `User` from AD so they are not coupled (and it would make unit testing easier). And `Employee` is your data model so should not contain `User` - you should have a view model that contains properties for `Employee` and `User`